# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1911 (note 1 of 1)

Tags: identificación-de-término

I only need to review one note for the year 1911 in my Great Grandfathers Civil Guard records. This is because the other note is a duplicate of one we already reviewed.

[image]

This is the transcribed (incomplete!) text I have so far:

> Xxx 19647 letra aido acintado a este individuo por la Tutoraron
> General el compañía de 4 años que coutar xxx xxx del año anterior xxx
> 12 puesta en couyeta de nota de en hara.
>
> El 2º Jefe

Thank you for your support in completing the transcribed text so that a translation can be made.

I am also wondering what that number represents?

---

#### Translation

Based on the suggested transcription the translation is:

> With the number 19647, this individual has been admitted by the
> General Intervention to the 4-year commitment that he contracted on
> the 1st September of the previous year, being credited with 12 pesetas
> in concept of entrance fee.

---

#### Update 1

I have quickly jumped to a 1914 note as I recalled it too mentions a number and the wording is a bit clearer:
[image]
So it looks to me that **concedido** should be **admitido** as per the second answer by @paribus-ceteris. I have updated the translation above.

---

#### Update 2

If I change the transcribed text to use **acreditándole** then the translation seems better than above. The final part of the sentence now reads:

> crediting him with 12 pesetas as an entrance fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Tutorarun seems to be a great word taken directly from Latin, here go my suggestions

> **Con el nº** 19647 **le ha sido concedido** a este individuo por la **Intervención**
> General el **compromiso** de 4 años que **contrajo en 1º Sepbre** (Septiembre) del año anterior **acreditándose**
> 12 **pesetas** en **concepto** de **cuota** de **entrada**.
>
> El 2º Jefe

Remember that his reenlistment was pending approval by the Intervención General. They did it here.

---

In relation with acreditándose vs acreditándole

The following sentences have the same meaning in Spanish

> Acreditándose 12 pesetas
>  12 pesetas se acreditaron
>  12 pesetas fueron
> acreditadas

If you change acreditándose by acreditándole you are just adding an indirect object: to him

> Acreditándole 12 pesetas
>  12 pesetas se le acreditaron
>  12 pesetas le fueron
> acreditadas

The relevant part is that **12 pesetas were credited**, were written down in the accounts of the Guardia Civil, in concept of entrance fee. It's clear that the one paying was your ancestor either way.

This said, I think that now I can see an l there. It may be **acreditándole**.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I remember about his reenlistment being pending. Makes sense. But the word **concedido** ... I might be wrong here but it really looks like the word starts **act** and not **con**.

Comment: I updated the transcribed text to use **adimitido**. See updated question.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think that you're right. It's clearly "admitido", my mistake. I've updated my answer in relation with acreditándose/acreditándole

Comment: Thanks. I am not really sure why my translation has now dropped the word **concept**. No worries.

Comment: I assume correctly that **19647** must be a **soldier** number?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think so.

Answer (score 1):

> Con el nº 19647 le ha sido admitido a este individuo por la
> Intervención General el compromiso de 4 años que contrajo en 1º de
> Sepbre (Septiembre) del año anterior acreditándole 12 pesetas en
> concepto de cuota de entrada.
>
> El 2º Jefe

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think that the 8th word is **admitido** (see updated question). But, towards the end you have **acreditando** but I think it looks like the word in the first answer of **acreditándose**.

Comment: Yeah, on a third look it even seems like it's "acreditándole" - but I guess it's basically the same meaning

Comment: But it does change the English and I think **acreditándole** makes it better.